# Time at which tuple was generated in Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to get the time at which a tuple was added in a table? Or more specifically, the tuples that have a timestamp in between say a given range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `auto_now_add=True` in a `DateField`

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Than according to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created.
>   Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is
>   always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.

Comment: I dont want to add any fields to my Models.

Comment: If there is a timestamp for every tuple thats added, I would like to access it and compare it with the current time. So if that difference is larger than say, 10 minutes I would like to filter it.

Comment: Oh yeas you are looking for `F class` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

`from django.db import F`
`from datetime import timedelta`
 `MyModel.objects.get(date__gt=F('date')+timedelta(minutes=10))`

Comment: But I am still looking for a timestamp. I mean there must be something internally. I was looking at this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signing/#verifying-timestamped-values
You think this could help?

Comment: I've never used before that class :(